# How can I create a scanner with array and also find min ,max and average of input user in java?

Tags: java

How can I create a `Scanner` with array and also find min ,max and average of user input in java?
Please give me a result or java code

Code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] name = new int[5];
        while (i <= 4) {
            System.out.print("Array Number " + i + ": = ");
            name[i] = s.nextInt();
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried ?

Comment: I have do scanner with array already but cannot find min,max and average

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate the average, you need to get the total of all the numbers and divide that by the size of your array – which you set at 5 (five).

You need to keep track of the minimum and maximum. For every value entered, you need to check whether it is lower than the current minimum. Similarly you need to check if the entered value is greater than the current maximum. You should initialize the minimum value to a very large number so that the first value entered will be lower allowing you to continue to track the minimum. Likewise, initialize the maximum to a very low number so that the first value entered will be larger.

Here is the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] name = new int[5];
        int total = 0;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        while (i <= 4) {
            System.out.print("Array Number " + i + ": = ");
            name[i] = s.nextInt();
            total += name[i];
            if (name[i] > max) {
                max = name[i];
            }
            if (name[i] < min) {
                min = name[i];
            }
            ++i;
        }
        System.out.println("min = " + min);
        System.out.println("max = " + max);
        double average = (double) total / 5;
        System.out.println("avg = " + average);
    }
}
```

I use a cast to `double` in the calculation of the average to ensure a `double` result. Without the cast, the result will be an `int`.

Here is output from a sample run of the above code:

```
Array Number 0: = 121
Array Number 1: = 49
Array Number 2: = 81
Array Number 3: = 4
Array Number 4: = 144
min = 4
max = 144
avg = 79.8
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do calculations on int array afterwards

```
Integer min = Arrays.stream(num).min(Integer::compare).get();
Integer max = Arrays.stream(num).max(Integer::compare).get();
Integer average Arrays.stream(num).average().getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about min,max,average you can do this

```
int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] name = new int[5];
    while (i <= 4) {
        
        System.out.print("Array Number " + i + ": = ");
        name[i] = s.nextInt();
        sum = sum +name[i];
        ++i;
        
    }
    
    Arrays.sort(name);
    System.out.println("Minimum = " + name[0]);
    System.out.println("Maximum = " + name[name.length-1]);
    System.out.println("Average = " + sum/5);
```

Comment: You can accept one of the answer where its satisfies you